# Help with Calculus Optimization Problem Circle Velocity!

Tags: calculus, derivatives, optimization, circles

Question: A bug is crawling along the curve defined by the equation $x^2=y^3+3y$. When the bug is at the point $(2,1)$, it is moving in such a way that its vertical velocity, $\dfrac{dy}{dt}$, is equal to $6$. What is its horizontal velocity, $\dfrac{dx}{dt}$, at that time?

I know that at this point we can utilize some sort of optimization, i.e find a given point where the derivative is equal to 0, but after racking my brain at this problem for a couple hours now, I really have to conclude that I'm stuck. Any help would be greatly appreciated, and if you do give an answer, please justify it as well! Thank you!

Comment: I don't see any circles here.  The curve is definitely not one.

Answer (score 0):

Using implicit differentiation by $t$, we have $\large{2x\frac{dx}{dt}=3y^2\frac{dy}{dt}+3\frac{dy}{dt}}$. Now let's substitute $x, y, \frac{dy}{dt}$ with their values and find $\frac{dx}{dt}$: $$2\cdot 2\cdot \frac{dx}{dt}=3\cdot 1^2 \cdot 6 +3\cdot 6$$
$$4\frac{dx}{dt}=36$$ 
$$\frac{dx}{dt}=9$$

Comment: So would it be 2(2) = 3(1)^2 + 3 ? Where am I supposed to go from here? Thanks!

Comment: In your comment, you left out the $dx/dt$ from the left side and the value of $dy/dt$ from the right side of your equation.

Comment: @mathperson1234: please see the updated answer